# dplyr group by union of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

`dplyr` can group by multiple columns (let's say ID columns), but that considers their intersection. So, all available combinations of those ID columns are considered as factors to consider different groups.

I'm looking for union of multiple columns, i.e. if two rows match by at least one of the ID column, I want them to be in same group.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43482086/11117265), there's a solution using the `igraph` package. I can't generalise this when I've more than two ID columns, because the documentation of `graph_from_data_frame` says the following:

> d
>
> A data frame containing a symbolic edge list in the first two columns. Additional columns are considered as edge attributes.

Here's an example:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

input_df <- tibble(id1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4 ,1),
                   id2 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1),
                   id3 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5))
input_df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>      id1   id2   id3
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     1
#>  2     2     2     2
#>  3     3     3     2
#>  4     4     1     1
#>  5     5     2     2
#>  6     2     3     3
#>  7     2     3     4
#>  8     3     2     2
#>  9     4     4     5
#> 10     1     1     5

grouped_df <- input_df %>%
  group_by(id1, id2, id3) %>%
  mutate(id = group_indices())
grouped_df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   id1, id2, id3 [10]
#>      id1   id2   id3    id
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1     1     1     1
#>  2     2     2     2     3
#>  3     3     3     2     7
#>  4     4     1     1     8
#>  5     5     2     2    10
#>  6     2     3     3     4
#>  7     2     3     4     5
#>  8     3     2     2     6
#>  9     4     4     5     9
#> 10     1     1     5     2

expected_df <- bind_cols(input_df,
                         id = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1))
expected_df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>      id1   id2   id3    id
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     1     1
#>  2     2     2     2     2
#>  3     3     3     2     2
#>  4     4     1     1     1
#>  5     5     2     2     2
#>  6     2     3     3     2
#>  7     2     3     4     2
#>  8     3     2     2     2
#>  9     4     4     5     1
#> 10     1     1     5     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the expected output. Row 2 belongs to group 2 because it doesn't match *anything* in group 1, and then row 3 also goes in group 2 because it has 1 match to group 2? What about row 7?

Comment: You can't uniquely identify such a group, because they wouldn't be mutually exclusive. This seems like a clustering issue.

Comment: @Marius `id1` and `id2` of row 7 match those of row 2, and hence ii's expeccted to be in the same group.

Comment: @Rohit For this particular dummy example, they are exclusive. It's indeed a type of clustering, I agree with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to the point where you can apply the `igraph` method by using `rdist::pdist` to create an adjacency matrix:

```
library(rdist)
library(igraph)

matches = rdist::pdist(input_df, metric = function(x, y) { any(x == y) })
g = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matches)
input_df$g = clusters(g)$membership
```

Might be slow on larger data due to the need to calculate pairwise distances with a custom function.

Comment: I was hoping for a `dplyr` solution, but it's fine too. Thanks.